# Collect bugs/issues in Next-Gen Jira Software projects

Tags: jira, bugs

I'm trying to find the proper way to collect bugs/issues in Jira's next-gen projects. Looks like this feature has been requested by many users.

How other PM's are dealing with bugs in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with **issue types**. Read more here on [set up issue types in next-gen projects](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/set-up-issue-types-in-next-gen-projects/). By default, next-gen software projects come with the *bug* standard issue type which is used...

> ... to track problems with software, such as user interface discrepancies,
> broken functionality, or other niggles experience by users.

To add bug issue types:

1. From your project's sidebar, select Project settings > Issue types.
2. From the sidebar, select + Add issue type.
3. Choose Bug issue type from the list.
4. Select Add.

If you're going to have many bugs and it's unlikely to do them all in a given Sprint, you might want to [enable backlog](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/enable-the-backlog/) because that way you won't have them all in your team’s board. To enable or disable the backlog:

1. Navigate to your next-gen software project.
2. In the sidebar, select Project Settings.
3. Select Features.
4. Enable the Backlog feature.